# 3 text fields, 1 pickerview, but, when using pickerView, the selection does not show in text field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

`UIPickerView` shows data but does not transfer to `UITextField`.

i've checked other post to compare my code, still cannot find a solution. your help is greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var hospNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mdNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectionsPickerView: UIPickerView!

    var hosp = ["hosp1", "hosp2", "hosp3"]
    var team = ["team1", "team2", "team3"]
    var mds = ["MD1", "MD2", "MD3"]

    var itemSelected = ""
    var textFieldSelected = UITextField()

    weak var pickerView: UIPickerView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        hospNameField.inputView = pickerView
        teamNameField.inputView = pickerView
        mdNameField.inputView = pickerView

        hospNameField.delegate = self
        teamNameField.delegate = self
        mdNameField.delegate = self

        self.pickerView = pickerView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textFieldSelected = textField
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if hospNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return hosp.count
        } else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return team.count
        } else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return mds.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if hospNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return hosp[row]
        } else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return team[row]
        } else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return mds[row]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
            let itemselected = hosp[row]
            hospNameField.text = itemselected
        } else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
            let itemselected = team[row]
            teamNameField.text = itemselected
        } else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
            let itemselected = mds[row]
            mdNameField.text = itemselected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `weak var pickerView: UIPickerView?` should not be weak variable, keep it `var pickerView: UIPickerView?`. And there is no use of `selectionsPickerView ` and `textFieldSelected` so remove these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have forgotten to subscribe the **delegate  and data sources** to the PickerView..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var hospNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mdNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectionsPickerView: UIPickerView!

    var hosp = ["hosp1", "hosp2", "hosp3"]
    var team = ["team1", "team2", "team3"]
    var mds = ["MD1", "MD2", "MD3"]

    var itemSelected = ""
    var textFieldSelected = UITextField()

    weak var pickerView: UIPickerView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        hospNameField.inputView = pickerView
        teamNameField.inputView = pickerView
        mdNameField.inputView = pickerView

        hospNameField.delegate = self
        teamNameField.delegate = self
        mdNameField.delegate = self

        self.pickerView = pickerView
        /**
         the below lines are mandatory for

         pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)

         to execute
         */
        self.pickerView?.delegate = self
        self.pickerView?.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textFieldSelected = textField
    }
    // add this delegate and reload here
  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) ->
        Bool {
            self.pickerView?.reloadAllComponents()
            return true
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if hospNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return hosp.count
        } else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return team.count
        } else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return mds.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if hospNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return hosp[row]
        } else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return team[row]
        } else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
            return mds[row]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        /**
         type here, need to check the responder for hospNameField also
         you have executed teamNameField.isFirstResponder twice
         */
        if hospNameField.isFirstResponder {
            let itemselected = hosp[row]
            hospNameField.text = itemselected
        } else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
            let itemselected = team[row]
            teamNameField.text = itemselected
        } else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
            let itemselected = mds[row]
            mdNameField.text = itemselected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, i was able to fix the issue. I was tired and did not notice the dup.lol..one more thing, when i change from lets say hosp UITextField to the team UITextField, the pickerView does not refresh and shows the hops options, but, i'm still able to select another team (hopefully i'm explaining myself). in the pickerView i have to scroll up and down few times for the other var to show. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: You can reload Picker view components to make this work. Can be done in the **didBeginEditing** Delegate of the textfield. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong in `didSelectRow`. check the first and second `if`, both run the same condition.

```
if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
   let itemselected = hosp[row]
   hospNameField.text = itemselected
} else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
   let itemselected = team[row]
   teamNameField.text = itemselected
} else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
   let itemselected = mds[row]
   mdNameField.text = itemselected
}
```

I think you should change the first `if` to `if hospNameField.isFirstResponder {..}`